# ui-sref pass params from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, parameter-passing

I need to pass a value from a view to another using `ui-sref` and the url params in `AngularJS` like this example:

```
<a ui-sref="new-qs({ portfolioId: {{id}} })">New (query string)</a>
```

where `{{id}}` is a variable from my controller. But I've got an `Error: [$parse:syntax]` error. Is it possible to do this operation, or I just can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<a ui-sref="new-qs({ 'portfolioId': id })">New (query string)</a>
```